# Create new databricks cluster from ADF linked service with InitScripts from abfss (azure blob )

Tags: azure-data-factory, cluster-computing, azure-databricks

Recently databricks depreciated DBFS init script, And I tried to set up databricks  linked service with InitScripts from abfss in ADF,  I am getting a file not found error.

[image]

The new cluster configuration is like below

[image]

But same tried from Databricks its worked, because we have option to configure which is init script location type.

[image]

But in ADF , I couldn't see any option to do the same ,

[image]

Please help me on this to resolve the issue.

I need to create new databricks cluster with init script read from azure blob storage(abfss) for every pipeline excecution.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the rest call to create the cluster with init script as required with abfss and then use this cluster in the databricks notebook directly.
- You can use the we activity to call the `Clusters 2.0` REST API to create a cluster as specified in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#:%7E:text=must%20authenticate.-,Create,-Endpoint) with authentication header where you specify bearer token (access token). The following is the body that you can use (You might have to add clusted configuration as well):

```
{
    "num_workers": null,
    "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 2,
        "max_workers": 8
    },
    "cluster_name": "cluster1",
    "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
    "spark_conf": {},
    "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2",
    "custom_tags": {},
    "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    },
    "autotermination_minutes": 120,
    "init_scripts": <script_path_here_as_specified_in_document>
}
```

[image]

- Use a wait activity until the cluster is created. I have used wait time as 300 seconds.
- Finally, use the cluster_id returned by the web activity for newly created cluster to run the notebook as `@activity('Web1').output.cluster_id`.

[image]

Comment: OK, let me check this one. Also can we delete this cluster after use?

Comment: You can use the same rest API for that as well.

Comment: Ok, let me try Thanks @Saideep Arikontham

Answer (score 0):

If you specified init script on `abfss://...` then you need to specify corresponding `spark.hadoop.fs...`  configurations in the "Cluster Spark conf" section (fill the data in `<...>` with corresponding values):

- `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type` set to `OAuth`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type` set to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint` set to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id` set to `<client_id>`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret` set to `{{secrets/<secret-scope>/<secret-key-name>}}` (it will fetch the key from the secret scope that contains client secret)

Comment: This will work only when, we are try to create from databricks it self not from ADF